# Submenu anomaly on hover

Tags: css, hover, submenu

I have a small CSS problem on this site: http://www.bioconact.com/. When I hover over 'Why BioConAct?' in the menu, a submenu pops up. But it's very difficult to click on one of the links in the submenu, as it often disappears before you reach it with your cursor. I can't discover when it stays and when it disappears and I'm quite stuck.

Does somebody have an idea about how to resolve this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a margin on the sub menu, remove this and you'll be able to reach the items.

Remove the `margin-top: 2px` from this class `.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu`  on line 1136 of your CSS

**UPDATED**

You could substitue the margin for a pseudo element with a height of 2px.

```
.sub-menu::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your quick answer! It resolved my problem, but I inserted the top margin to get the submenu started on the same height as the main body of the website. Can I still achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Stefaan Ive added a little snippet to give you back your margin and allows your menu to work.

Comment: Hi there Aaron, thanks for the code snippet! That did the trick ; )